# How to place HTML tags in a CSV?

Tags: php, html, csv

I have an excel sheet. In this excel sheet it contains `Parts Number`, `Summary`, `Brand`, `Status`. I would like to be able to import CSV data which contains text that already has html so I don’t have to apply all the formatting after import.

In this new csv, it should only contain 3 columns, **Parts Number**, **Summary** and **html table**. In this **html table**, it contains `Parts Number`, `Summary`, `Brand`, `Status`.

I have already created a table using php and it worked, now I am having difficulty trying to bring the table to csv.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("Book1.csv","r");
$file2 = fopen("Book2.csv","w");
$data = [];
$description = '<table class="table">';
while($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
$data[] = $row; //Get all the data
}
if($data){  
    $n_columns = count($data[0]); //Get number of columns 
}
$description .= '<table border="1">'; 
for ($col = 0; $col < $n_columns; $col++) {
    $description .= '<tr>';
    foreach ($data as $row_k => $row) {
        if ($row_k == 0) {
            $description .= '<th>';
        } else {
            $description .= '<td>';
        }

        $description .= $row[$col] ?? '';
        if ($row_k == 0) {
            $description .= '</th>';
        } else {
            $description .= '</td>';
        }
    }
    $description .= '</tr>';
    fputcsv($file2, $data); // line 50
}
$description .= '</table>';
fclose($file);
fclose($file2);
?>
```

I am desperate, any help is appreciated.

Comment: `fputcsv()` is for writing a single **row**, just how `fgetcsv()` is for reading a single **row**

Comment: Can you please share some example data of `Book1.csv`

Comment: @JacobMulquin, I've updated the question to include an image of Book1.csv

Comment: So your current way of approaching the problem will have the HTML table being a list of all products within each product row. Are you looking to group by parts number/summary/brand and having each table be a list of the country and discounted status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should accomplish the task. It uses 3 functions, `array_to_csv`, `csv_to_array` and `build_table`.

```
<?php

function csv_to_array($filename, $header_row=true)
{
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
        
    if ($header_row === true)
        $header = fgetcsv($handle);

    $data = [];
    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        if ($header_row)
            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        else
            $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}

function array_to_csv($data, $filename, $header_row=true)
{
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w');

    if ($header_row == true) {
        $header = array_keys($data[0]);
        fputcsv($handle, $header);
    }

    foreach ($data as $line) {
        fputcsv($handle, $line);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

function transpose_array($array)
{
    $headers = array_keys($array[0]);
    $transposed = [];

    foreach ($array as $row) {
        foreach ($headers as $header) {
            if (!isset($transposed[$header]))
                $transposed[$header] = [];
         
            $transposed[$header][] = $row[$header];
        }
    }

    return $transposed;
}

function build_table($array)
{
    $transposed = transpose_array($array);

    $table = '<table><tbody>';
    foreach ($transposed as $heading => $row) {
        $table .= '<tr><th>' . $heading .'</th>';
        foreach ($row as $element) {
            $table .= '<td>' . $element . '</td>';
        }
        $table .= '</tr>';
    }
    $table .= '</tbody></table>';
    return $table;
}

$book1 = csv_to_array('Book1.csv');
$book2 = [];
foreach ($book1 as $row) {
    $key = $row['Parts Number'];
    if (!isset($book2[$key])) {
        $book2[$key] = [
            'Parts Number' => $key,
            'Summary' => $row['Summary']
        ];
    }
    $book2[$key]['rows'][] = $row;
}

foreach ($book2 as &$product) {
    $product['html table'] = build_table($product['rows']);
    unset($product['rows']);
}
unset($product);
$book2 = array_values($book2);

array_to_csv($book2, 'Book2.csv');
```

Book1.csv contains:

```
Parts Number,Summary,Brand,Status,Country
6SE1200-1EA70-1,SIMOVERT P 6,Siemens,Discontinued,Germany
6SE1200-1EA70-1,SIMOVERT P 6,Siemens,Discontinued,France
6SE1200-1EA70-1,SIMOVERT P 6,Siemens,In Stock,England
6SE3012-0BA00,SIMOVERT P M,Siemens,Discontinued,-
```

Book2.csv output:

```
"Parts Number",Summary,"html table"
6SE1200-1EA70-1,"SIMOVERT P 6","<table><tbody><tr><th>Parts Number</th><td>6SE1200-1EA70-1</td><td>6SE1200-1EA70-1</td><td>6SE1200-1EA70-1</td></tr><tr><th>Summary</th><td>SIMOVERT P 6</td><td>SIMOVERT P 6</td><td>SIMOVERT P 6</td></tr><tr><th>Brand</th><td>Siemens</td><td>Siemens</td><td>Siemens</td></tr><tr><th>Status</th><td>Discontinued</td><td>Discontinued</td><td>In Stock</td></tr><tr><th>Country</th><td>Germany</td><td>France</td><td>England</td></tr></tbody></table>"
6SE3012-0BA00,"SIMOVERT P M","<table><tbody><tr><th>Parts Number</th><td>6SE3012-0BA00</td></tr><tr><th>Summary</th><td>SIMOVERT P M</td></tr><tr><th>Brand</th><td>Siemens</td></tr><tr><th>Status</th><td>Discontinued</td></tr><tr><th>Country</th><td>-</td></tr></tbody></table>"
```

Comment: it worked! however I just want 1 product number along with the product info in one cell for the table, how do I fix that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, that's why I asked about grouping earlier. You said you wanted each table on each row to contain all items of the csv. Anyway play around with the foreach loop and see what you can come up with :)

Comment: my apologies I should have phrase it better. I just want one table to contain the information in that same row. So one table should only have 1 product information (`Product Number`, `Summary`, `Brand`, `Status` and `Country`)

Comment: thanks Jacob! Quick question, if I would want the header to be on the left and product information to be on the right, how do I achieve this?

Comment: @Sam https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54294865/vertical-table-headings-with-html-and-css

Comment: thanks for the link! but the answer isn't helping my case. I know that the issue is due to the tr meaning you coded all the header into a single row.

Comment: Could you make a drawing and put it in your question, I can't picture what you mean.

Comment: ofc, I've updated the question :)

Comment: Ahhh ok yes I see what you mean. What that's called is "transposing". Check the updated answer